# Openldap setting up olcOverlay: ppolicy

Tags: centos7, openldap, password-policy

**Question:** Why am I failing to add the objectclass pwdPolicy to cn=PasswordDefaults?

---

**Background Information**

I am new to LDAP and I'm stumbling through various tutorials and other tips online to create a directory that will handle user information for me. I'm trying to create an LDAP server that will contain user information and enforce a password policy. To achieve this, I believe that I need to add the pwdPolicy objectclass to ou=Policies to my LDAP server running 2.4.40. I'm loosely following these tutorials:

```
{
  Password Policy tutorial: https://tobrunet.ch/articles/openldap-password-policy-overlay/, 
  Getting started with OpenLDAP and CentOS7: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=1, 
  Default and User Specific Password Policy: http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html
}
```

I have a directory laid out like this:

```
-> Root stuff
  -> dc=example,dc=com
    -> cn=Manager (The olcRootDN)
    -> ou=User
       -> *Several entries with objectClasses {posixAccount, shadowAccount, inetOrgPerson}*
    -> ou=Policies (Not sure if this is here because not visible in Apache Directory Studio)
       -> cn=passwordDefault
```

Here is what I have done to try to use the ppolicy.

Steps 1-3 loosely follow commands from the *[OpenLDAP with OLC](https://tobrunet.ch/articles/openldap-password-policy-overlay/)* section *OpenLDAP Password Policy overlay*

**Step 1:** Load the ppolicy schema into the OLC with this command:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.ldif
```

**Understanding of Step 1:** adds cn={5}ppolicy.ldif to /.../slap.d/cn=config/cn=schema

**Step 2:** Load the module with this command:

```
ldapadd -D "cn=config" -W -f addPpolicyOverlay.ldif
```

contents of addPpolicyOverlay.ldif

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModuleLoad: ppolicy.la
```

**Understanding of Step 2:** adds cn=module{0}.ldif to /.../slapd.d/cn=config.

**Step 3:** Configure the ppolicy overlay with this command:

```
ldapadd -D "cn=config" -W -f configurePpolicyOverlay.ldif
```

contents of configurePpolicyOverlay.ldif

```
dn: olcOverlay=ppolicy,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcPPolicyConfig
olcOverlay: ppolicy
olcPPolicyDefault: cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com
olcPPolicyHashCleartest: FALSE
olcPPolicyUseLockout: FALSE
olcPPolicyForwardUpdates: FALSE
```

**Understanding of Step 3:** Makes a database and uses ppolicy overlay. Makes ou=Policies in my domain dc=example,dc=com. I am unable to explore ou=Policies in Apache Directory Studio even though I believe it is exists in dc=example,dc=com

**Questions about Step 3:** Do I now have a working default password policy?

**Step 4:** Fails to add the pwdPolicy objectclass to olcOverlay={0}ppolicy with this command:

```
ldapmodify -a -D "cn=config" -W -f configureDefaultPpolicy.ldif
```

**Error:**`ldapmodify: invalid format (line 5) entry: "olcOverlay={0}ppolicy,cn=olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"`

contents of configureDefaultPpolicy.ldif

```
dn: olcOverlay={0}ppolicy,cn=oldDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config]
changetype: modify
olcObjectClasses: pwdPolicy
cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdInHistory: 50
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdMinLength: 8
```

**Questions about Step 4:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8hqX.jpg
 (Not trusted enough to embed pictures :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Understanding of Step 3:** Makes a database and uses ppolicy overlay. Makes ou=Policies in my domain dc=example,dc=com. I am unable to explore ou=Policies in Apache Directory Studio even though I believe it is exists in dc=example,dc=com

It does not create anything in the database `dc=example,dc=com`, it just set some configuration for the ppolicy overlay used by this database.

> **Questions about Step 3:** Do I now have a working default password policy?

No, as per your tutorial, you have to create these branches in the database `dc=example,dc=com` to be able to put a ppolicy :

*It is not to be put in the `cn=config` but in the database `dc=example,dc=com`*

```
dn: ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com
ou: Policies
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: passwordDefault
sn: passwordDefault
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdCheckQuality: 0
pwdMinAge: 0
pwdMaxAge: 0
pwdMinLength: 8
pwdInHistory: 5
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 0
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdExpireWarning: 0
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdMustChange: FALSE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

For the question about step 4, I am not able to see imgur images behind my professional proxy, but the fact you try to import the ppolicy into the cn=config should be the main problem.

Comment: so I added the ldif above to dc=example,dc=com. Now do my users in ou=user,dc=example,dc=com obey the rules set in ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com?

Comment: I appears to have worked because I have locked out an account. Is there a way to tell if a user has been locked out or needs to change its password?

Comment: @hededo [See this](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html#operationalattributes) for more informations about what you can find in the user entry

Comment: @hededo How were you logging in when locking out an account?
Did you use ldappasswd binding as a user?
Which object class do your user accounts have in the database?